# How do I get toggle button working with php

Tags: php

Bootstrap Toggle button seems to refuse to work with php.

[See Code](https://pastebin.com/JncD1DfJ)

```
<div style="width:100%; height:auto; padding:10px 0; background:#0F71BA; font-family:Verdana; color:#fff;" onclick="toggleDept()">
        <span style="margin-left:10px;"> Select Department  </span>
        <i class="fa-chevron-down fa" style="float:right; margin-right:10px; cursor:pointer"></i>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; background:#fff; height:400px; overflow:auto; display:none" id="dept-sub-list-mobile">
        <?php...
```

[Click Departments dropdown in mobile mode to understand the issue](https://projectguruss.com)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have `toggleDept` javascript function on the page; 
add the code below into your javascript file

```
function toggleDept(){ 
    $('#dept-sub-list-mobile').toggle(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In javascript you can do like this:-

```
 function toggleDept(){ 
    var x = document.getElementById("dept-sub-list-mobile");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `toggleDept()` function javascript function on the page. For toggle functionality we use `jQuery` [toggle()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp) method. Here is the code :

```
function toggleDept(){ 
    $('#dept-sub-list-mobile').toggle(); 
}
```